# matchOnUriPrefix=true does not seem to be working

Tags: wildfly, restlet, undertow

I am using:

- wildlfy 10.1.0 final
- Camel 2.19.1
- Camel Java DSL RouteBuilder

In my RouteBuilder.configure I have the following from:

```
from("undertow:http://localhost:" + portNum + "/DataplatformESB/v3?matchOnUriPrefix=true&httpMethodRestrict=post,get,put,options,patch,delete")
```

When I test to `"localhost:8080/DataplatformESB/v3"` with `GET`, `PUT`, or `PATCH`, they all work fine. But when I test to `"localhost:8080/DataplatformESB/v3/anythingelse"` I'll get a `404 (page not found)` in return. In the Wildfly log it stats: `"Matched prefix path /DataplatformESB for path /DataplatformESB/v3/anythingelse"`. So for me it looks like the `"matchOnUriPrefix=true"` is not working.

I have already tested with `from("restlet:http://localhost:" + portNum + "/DataplatformESB/v3?matchOnUriPrefix=true&httpMethodRestrict=post,get,put,options,patch,delete")`, but that does not work as well.

I have also tried it with the `restConfiguration` and `.componentProperty("matchOnUriPrefix", "true")` but also no luck.

Does anyone has an idea why the `matchOnUriPrefix=true` does not seem to work for me?

Answer (score 0):

I have done some further research and found out the folliwing:

I got the undertow test project from `https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components/camel-undertow/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/undertow/UndertowPrefixMatchingTest.java` and run/tested in it in my NetBeans.

The code is:
`from("undertow:http://localhost:{{port}}/bar?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
    .transform(bodyAs(String.class).append(" Matching prefix"))
    .to("mock:bar");`

This runs fine and returns OK when the URL starts with the prefix: `"bar"`. So `"bar/foo"` returns OK as well.

But when I paste this code into the Wildfly Camel Rest Swagger example (there is no Wildfly Camel Rest example) from the website `https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-camel-examples/tree/master/camel-rest-swagger`, then I only get an OK when testing with `"bar"` as path. 
Using `"bar/foo"` result in a 404 return code.

Im still using Wildfly 10.1 final and Camel 2.19.1.

So what is causing the difference in output? What do I have to change in Wildfly to get it working?

Is the option `matchOnUriPrefix` default disabled/ignored on Wildfly?

Answer (score 0):

When using the Wildfly-Camel 2.18.3 on the Wildlfly installation it seems to work.
It looks like the default value for matchOnUriPrefix is changed or the handling of this property.
In that case it seems to me that this introduced the bug as described above.